# Clarification on choosing silverlight to build a new website

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, html, telerik

2 questions really:

I had recently chosen to go with silverlight, expressions, and Telerik silverlight controls to make a website. But I just read that the default browser for windows 8 and future IEs will not allow plugins unless the user uses the non-default desktop mode browser which will continue to support plugins. Have I got that right? That all sites that use silverlight will need to be re-written to Html 5 or something?

I have seen a list of browsers supported with silverlight, I noted that IE 6 and IE 7 for windows 7 isn't supported, but does that mean the plugin isn't installed by default rather than not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have I got that right? Yes. No browser plugins are supported in iOS / Win 8 Metro browser / Win Phone7+. Your only option for a website is Html / Html5  + Javascript + CSS

The reason for not supporting ie6 / ie7 on windows 7 is that windows 7 comes with IE 8 by default so you cannot install IE6/IE7 on windows 7 and therefore silverlight is not supported on those versions :)

Comment: Yup. Its not as cool as silverlight but asp.net MVC is the best option when it comes to modern web frameworks (django / ruby etc) since you get to still use EntityFramework / Visual Studio and other cool MS technologies.

Comment: Its annoying that telerik's kendo ui is not mature to have all of the asp.net ajax controls features, that would be the perfect alternative. That is such a shame about silverlight though- bloody MS!